# Bash string operations unwanted remove new line characters

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm completely new to bash scripting so excuse me....
I am trying to combine some html content with a template that contains standard headings, the template has a place-holder "REPLACEME" which I thought I could just find and replace on. The loop simply repeats the operation on all the files in the directory.

```
REPLACEME="REPLACEME"
for file in *.html
do
TEMPLATE=$(<../template/template.html)
CONTENT=$(<$file)
OUTPUT="${TEMPLATE/"$REPLACEME"/"$CONTENT"}"
echo $OUTPUT > ../compiled/$file
done
```

This works but the resulting html file has been stripped of new line characters, which makes it look like junk! Can anyone help?

Comment: Perhaps an easier solution is the perl pie. Specifically: `perl -pi -e 's/search/replace/g' *.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
echo $OUTPUT > ../compiled/$file
```

With:

```
echo "$OUTPUT" > ../compiled/$file
```

The shell performs *word splitting* on unquoted variables.  With the default value for `IFS`, this means that all sequences of whitespace, which includes tabs and newlines, are replaced with a single blank.  To prevent that, put the variable in double-quotes as shown above.

Comment: @heemayl Yes, that's true and, if it was a problem that we had too many newlines at the end, we could use `echo -n` (bash) or `printf` (POSIX).  But, the code `TEMPLATE=$(<../template/template.html)` strips the final newline from the input.  Consequently, for us here, the final newline is missing and it is good that `echo` adds it back.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` you could achieve it like below :

```
sed -i 's/REPLACEME/new_text/g' /path/to/your/template.html
```

The `-i` option in sed is for inplace edit & the `g` option is for global substitution.

**Edit 1:**

If you need to use a variable inside `sed` you can do it this way

```
var="Sometext";
sed -i "s/REPLACEME/$var/g" /path/to/your/template.html
```

Mind the double quotes here, it makes the shell expand variables.

---

If your system supports gnu-awk (`gawk`) you may achieve the above with

```
gawk '
{
$0=gensub(/REPLACEME/"NEWTEXT","g",$0)
printf "%s\n", $0
}' < /path/to/your/template.html > newtemplate.html && mv newtemplate.html template.html
```

Comment: I tried sed but I couldn't get it to accept a variable where you have "new_text". It always replaced REPLACEME with the variable name? I would love to know how to make it work!

Comment: @Jimnotgym : See the edit please and if it works kindly accept the answer